# CSS and JS are not loading in subdomain

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to load CSS and JS files from a sub-domain.

The URL of my sub-domain is `https://example.example.com`

I am trying to load the style-sheets with the following statement:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

When I navigate to `https://example.example.com` I can see that the style-sheet is not loaded.

When I look at my web console, I can see the following error message:

```
GET https://www.example.com/vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

According to the message the file should not available. But when I click on the link I can see the content of `bootstrap.min.css`. So my conclusion is the that the style-sheet does exist.

I also tried to upload the style-sheet to the page for the sub-domain. I tried the following statements:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.example.com/vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/example/vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

All of these returned the same error code.

When I navigate to `https://www.example.com/example` instead of `https://example.example.com` I can see that the style-sheet is working.

Does someone know how I can solve this problem?

**Update:**

I think pointing directly (https://www.example.com/vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css) to the page is always correct. There should be something else but I cannot discover what is wrong.

The style-sheet works on the pages

```
https://www.example.com/example/index.php
https://www.example.com/another/index.php
https://www.example.com/another/testpage.php
https://another.example.com/index.php
```

The style-sheet does not work on the following pages

```
https://example.example.com/index.php
https://another.example.com/testpage.php
```

Like you can see. The index page of the other subdomain (subdomain: another) is working. testpage.php is using the same style-sheets with the same pointing method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Also the https://www.example.com/another/testpage.php is returning 404

**Update 2:**

Here is my httpd configuration:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:80 >
    ServerName www.example.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.example.com example.example.com 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/domains/example.com/public_html/example
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/domains/example.com/public_html/example/cgi-bin/
    UseCanonicalName OFF
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin admin
        #RGroups apache access
        RGroups @none
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.example.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.example.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.example.error.log
    <Directory /home/admin/domains/example.com/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine ON
        php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@example.com'
        php_admin_value mail.log /home/admin/.php/php-mail.log
        php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear/:/dev/urandom:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php72/lib/php/
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:443 >
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/example.com.cert.combined
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/example.com.cacert 
    ServerName www.example.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.example.com example.example.com 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/domains/example.com/private_html/example
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/domains/example.com/public_html/example/cgi-bin/
    UseCanonicalName OFF
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin admin
        #RGroups apache access
        RGroups @none
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.example.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.example.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.example.error.log
    <Directory /home/admin/domains/example.com/private_html>
        php_admin_flag engine ON
        php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@example.com'
        php_admin_value mail.log /home/admin/.php/php-mail.log
        php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear/:/dev/urandom:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php72/lib/php/
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Update 3:**

Map structure:

```
www.example.com
- example (subdomain)
-- index.php
- another (subdomain)
-- index.php
-- testpage.php
- vendors (map)
```

Working:

```
Pointing from www.example.com/another/index.php and another.example.com/index.php to the `vendors` map.
```

Not working:

```
Pointing from www.example.com/example/index.php and example.example.com/index.php to the `vendors` map.
Pointing from www.example.com/another/testpage.php and another.example.com/testpage.php to the `vendors` map.
```

**Update 4:**

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxx >
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/example.com.cert.combined
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/example.com.cacert
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com example.com 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/domains/example.com/private_html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/domains/example.com/public_html/cgi-bin/
    UseCanonicalName OFF
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin admin
        #RGroups apache access
        RGroups @none
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.error.log
    <Directory /home/admin/domains/example.com/private_html>
        php_admin_flag engine ON
        php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@example.com'
        php_admin_value mail.log /home/admin/.php/php-mail.log
        php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear/:/dev/urandom:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php72/lib/php/
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: 404 Not Found seems pretty clear. We don't know anything about your server configuration or why you think that URL should find a resource.

Comment: Why *should* it load at `example.example.com`? Have you configured a DNS wildcard to map all subdomains to your top level domain?

Comment: Why all these downvotes?

The resource exists. I can view the pagesource and click on the resource: https://www.example.com/vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css. I also use the same resource on https://www.example.com/example.

Comment: I also configured a DNS wildcard. The DNS wildcard looks like:
example A xxx.xxx.xx.xxx (server IP)

Comment: hard reload/clear cache?

Comment: I always clear my cache and open the page in incognito mode. I had some issues before with the cache, since then I know that i should clear always my cache. The cache is not the problem in this case.

Answer (score 3):

without knowing more of your set up, you might want to look at your nginx or httpd config. My guess is that your pathing is not correct resulting in a 404.

if both the domain and subdomain are pointing to the same document root and serving files from the same location, you would probably need to search in example.example.com/example.

if you are trying to get it to load on example.example.com then you should set the document root to the /example subdirectory in your project.

Without more information that's the best guess I have is that your server config is wrong.

As others have noted, you must also make sure that the DNS entries are configured correctly as well to include the sub domain and point it to the correct server.

Update:

Here is an example of what my virtualhost looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.mySite.com
        DocumentRoot /srv/www/mySite/web/frontend/public

        <Directory /srv/www/mySite/web/frontend/public>
                Require all granted

                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteBase /
                RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
        </Directory>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/mycert"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/mykey"
        SSLCertificateChainFile "/path/to/chainfile"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.mySite.com
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that the rewrite rules are because I'm running a vue app that has frontend routing, so you could completely ignore that if you wanted.  I would start out simple with your configuration just to make sure you can serve files from the directories you're expecting to serve from.  Only once I could access some basic html files from the domain and subdomain would I add the complexities.

If you're having issues, try stripping down as much as you can to start to reduce the complexities then start working your way back up.

Update 2:

For completeness, OP determined in this case "Require all granted" was missing

Comment: I can confirm that the DNS entries are correct. I use the same configuration for other subdomains. The same configuration works for other subdomains. I agree that there must be a difference, but I dont think that the difference is in the DNS configuration.

I am navigating directly to `https://www.example.com/vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css` (no subdomain) why should that result in a 404. I can understand that `./vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css` returns into a 404, but navigating directly should not return a 404.

Comment: What do I need to check in my httpd configuration? I didnt change this configuration before.

And like I said before. Other subdomains are working. I had issues with this subdomain. Is httpd not a general configuration?

Comment: basically i'd check the document root for the domain and subdomain to see where they are being served from.  If both have the same document root then you must access them in the same way (example.example.com/example  or example.com/example)  you should also check to make sure you have given proper permissions to access the files within httpd

Comment: without seeing your httpd / virtualhost configuration it's really difficult to say for sure, though.  if you posted the configuration and a basic idea of the project structure it would help a lot

Comment: I have posted my httpd configuration, see `Update 2` in my first post. Not sure if this is what you need. Also see `Update 3` for the map structure.

Comment: have you tried adding Require all granted for the directory you are trying to access?  I don't see that in there

Comment: also your 443 and 80 are pointing to different locations (private vs public html sites), make sure you are correctly using http or https depending on what you're trying to access if the folder structures are different.  Do you also have the virtualhost config for straight up example.com?  there are a lot of domains and subdomains you're trying to work with so it can get complex.  it might be worth setting up a dummy project that's less complicated that has a similar folder structure you want, then you can transfer over what you make and make it fit to what you have

Comment: No, I did not add 'require all granted' for the directory. Is this something I need to add to the `httpd configuration`?

Comment: In fact there is a 'public html site'. But I dont use the public html. When you try to access http:// it is automatically directing you to https://

Comment: if that's the case I would clean that up a bit to make it more ledgible.  Normally I am pretty sure it's good practice to put Require all granted to make sure you have permissions to access those files.  Default settings in httpd tend to lock things down for security.  This is so a rogue agent can't surf your entire folder structure when you didn't intend.  A byproduct may be that the files simply arent accessible.  I don't know that it's your problem, but I would add it either way.

Comment: I will add an example of what my virtual host looks like for you as well

Comment: also remember, document root is from where all files will be served. all url subdirectories need to be based on the document root

Comment: The problem is solved. After adding `Require all granted` and `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` the problem was solved. Thank you for your help

Comment: (need to wait 9 more hours to award the bounty)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `<base>` in head before to load css and js file, your's file will be loaded correctly here an example:

```
<head>
    <base href="https://dominio.com/subdomain_folder">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
</head>
```